# creating RadEditor dynamically asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radeditor, telerik-editor

I want to add RadEditor dynamically. It is getting added to the page but as soon as postback occurs i get **Multiple controls with the same ID 'EditorRibbonBarResourcesHolder' were found.** Below is the code that i am using to add control dynamically.

```
RadEditor editor = new RadEditor();
editor.ID = "editor_" + itemTypeattribute.ItemAttributeID + rand.Next();
cellAttributeValue.Controls.Add(editor);
editor.DialogOpener.ID = "editor_dialopOpener_" + itemTypeattribute.ItemAttributeID;
editor.DialogOpener.Window.ID = "editor_dialopOpener_window_"+ ItemTypeattribute.ItemAttributeID;
editor.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.AutoID;
editor.EnableEmbeddedScripts = true;
editor.Height = 200;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where in the page lifecycle are you adding in the editor?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to use a radeditor "dynamically" I have it on the page from the start with visible=false and then show it when I need it.

Comment: It works fine but when i click any other toolbar buttons inside Editor then it gives me error "Multiple controls with the same ID 'EditorRibbonBarResourcesHolder' were found".

Comment: Do you get the error when *not* creating it dynamically and having it on the page from the start? What is the html markup you are using in this case?

Comment: scenario was that i had to create 1 or more editor dynamically based on few conditions. So didn't got any luck using RadEditor... so i have moved to using other HtmlEditor. Thanks for your help.